# Best way to store text values to access with PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I need to store two text values (user's e-mail and job title) in Azure Blob Storage to feed a dashboard in powerBI.

Is this possible in Azure Blob Storage? Am I better off using another datasource?

I also want to be able to write values to the storage in my Java application.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly store the text value to blob storage, but you can keep the text value in CSV file and then you can upload the file to the blob storage.
you can access the CSV file in PowerBI by importing the CSV file in PowerBI using Get Data Option in PowerBI.

Other way is you can insert the text value directly to COSMOS DB and then import that COSMOS DB using the Get Data in Power BI also.

**Note**:  Java - [Microsoft Azure Storage Client SDK for Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage) on Maven. This Azure Storage SDK has the ability to connect to Azure Cosmos DB accounts using the Table API.

Azure Cosmos DB Table API accounts use this format:

```
 http://<storage account>.table.cosmosdb.azure.com/<table>
```

This is how you can connect to PowerBI using blob storage and Cosmos DB.
[image]

Follow the below reference for how to feed the value in PowerBI dashboard.

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-access-data-from-azure-blob-storage-using-power-bi/